# How To share using access token on linkedin

Tags: ios, objective-c, linkedin-api

I have generated Access token by using  OAuth 2.0

```
-(void)request:(NSString *)code
{        
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:accessTokenEndPoint]];

    NSString *grantType = @"authorization_code";        
    NSString *postParameter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"grant_type=%@&code=%@&redirect_uri=%@&client_id=%@&client_secret=%@",grantType,code,encodedRdirectURL,linkedInKey,linkedInSecret];


    NSData *postdata = [postParameter dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];                
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    request.HTTPBody = postdata;                
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error)

      {
          NSHTTPURLResponse *responseHttp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
          NSInteger statusCode = [responseHttp statusCode];

          if (statusCode == 200)
          {
              NSDictionary *parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:NULL];                 

              AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
              appDelegate.TokenAccess =[parsedObject objectForKey:@"access_token"];

          }

      }] resume];
}
```

This is How i integrated linkedin

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    linkedInKey = @"7";

    linkedInSecret = @"u";

    authorizationEndPoint = @"https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization";

    accessTokenEndPoint = @"https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken";

    _webview.delegate = self;


    [self startAuthorisation];

}

-(void)startAuthorisation
{


    NSString *responseType = @"code";


    NSString *redirectURL = @"https://www.google.co.in";

    encodedRdirectURL = [redirectURL stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:NSCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet];


    NSString *state = @"RandomString";


    NSString *scope = @"w_share";



    NSString *authorizationURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?response_type=%@&client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&state=%@&scope=%@",authorizationEndPoint,responseType,linkedInKey,encodedRdirectURL,state,scope];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:authorizationURL]];


    [_webview loadRequest:request];

}
```

Now how to share image and text using access token. is there is any api available ? as I don't want to use linkedin sdk.

Please help Thank you

Comment: It's not possible to do without using their sdk. How do you know their endpoints ?

Comment: Why not as i have even fetched data from using that access token and the end point is like this authorizationEndPoint = @"https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization";
    
    accessTokenEndPoint = @"https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken";

Comment: OAuth is to only get the access Token. You can do nothing with it without the sdk. Access token is to say that you have a valid session to do something. And to do something, you have to use their sdk.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Rest API's](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api) Once the Authentication will over, you can share using the [Rest API](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api) Please go through these 2 documentations.